# assigning id to new added object in ngrepeat

Tags: angularjs, x-editable

i am using Xeditable Angular,

Working fine.

The issue is when i added a new data as a new row to table. and i made a ajax call to server, server saved it, and returned new id, i want to assign this id to the new added model. how i do that.

When i added a new item, it added instantly to model by xeditable, its fine, but its id field is null, i want to change the null to the return value from server. how select the item of last edited by its track by id

```
    <tr ng-cloak ng-repeat="school in results = (content.data  | filter: content.search | orderBy:sortType:sortReverse | offset: (content.currentPage-1) * content.pageSize | limitTo: content.pageSize) track by school.id">
      <td><input type="checkbox" ng-model="content.deleteList[school.id]" ng-checked="content.head"></td><td>{{school.id}}</td> .......................................
```

Only part of desplayed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is update the id when you get a reply form the server :

```
$scope.addData = function(user) {
    yourFactory.addData(user).then(function(result) {
        user.id = result.data.id;
    });
}
```

I may be able to help you better if you provide more code

Comment: @lggy i am using angular xeditable to add data, i am using add a row method, there is only two options, onaftersave and onbeforesave, i think this will not work with it, i will try.